# How can I optimize the MYSQL query related to regions

Tags: mysql

- Country table has around 2 records.
- State table has around 50 records.
- City table has around 6000 records.
- Zipcode table has around 500000 records

Approximate exicution time to fetch data is around 12-15 minutes.

How can I optimize below query:

```
SELECT Country.id          AS Country_id, 
       Country.country     AS Country_country, 
       Country.countrycode AS Country_countrycode, 
       State.id            AS State_id, 
       State.statecode     AS State_statecode, 
       City.id             AS City_id, 
       City.city           AS City_city, 
       Zipcode.id          AS Zipcode_id, 
       Zipcode.zipcode     AS Zipcode_zipcode 
FROM   c_country Country 
       LEFT JOIN c_state State 
              ON Country.id = ( State.country_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN c_city City 
              ON State.id = ( City.state_id ) 
       LEFT JOIN c_zipcode Zipcode 
              ON City.id = ( Zipcode.city_id )
```

Below are the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `c_city` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7027 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `c_state` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `statecode` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `c_country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `countrycode` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `c_zipcode` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=539420 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Below is the screenshot of EXPLAIN SELECT:

[image]

Comment: Can you run the query with explain  ?

Comment: I need all data from the table and it is taking around 12 to 15 minutes to fetch the records from database. I need the better way for this.

Comment: Please check the question. I added the table structures.

Comment: Thanks now I can answer, it would be even better if you write the result for "Explain Select..." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Add indexes, that will help a lot. Alternatively, you can reorganize your tables and/or use temporary tables that bind columns from different tables into one table.

Comment: OK, you have PK indexes for the referenced columns, that should be enough. Maybe the *fetch* time is too long - that you can not really help about, but it shouldn't take 15 minutes.

Comment: @DanielE. I added EXPLAIN SELECT exicution. Please check on it.

Answer (score 0):

for try to improve performanbce you could add  index for

```
table c_zipcode  column  city_id
table c_city column  state_id 
table  c_state column  country_id
```

or  for resolve too all the columns values using the index

```
table c_zipcode  column  city_id, zipcode
table c_city column  state_id, city
table  c_state column  country_id , statecode
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is very slow because there is some index missing. You didn't declare any Foreign Key, in mysql InnoDB, Foreign Key are important because they are warranty for the data integrity but MySQL create automatically index on this foreign keys too.

a link to explain : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105469/performance-impact-of-adding-a-foreign-key-to-a-1m-rows-table

You have to alter the tables to add foreign keys :

```
ALTER TABLE c_city ADD CONSTRAINT fk_state_id FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES c_state(id);
ALTER TABLE c_state ADD CONSTRAINT fk_country_id FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES c_country(id);
ALTER TABLE c_zipcode ADD CONSTRAINT fk_city_id FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES c_city (id);
```